# Aws lamndaの環境変数

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

お世話になっております。

AWS Lambdaの環境変数について、質問させてください。

環境変数は、各Lambda固有のもので、複数のLambdaに対応するような設定は可能でしょうか。

複数のLambdaから一つの環境変数にアクセスして、共通の情報を取得したいと思っております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambdaの環境変数の設定は、各Lambda Function毎に指定するものなので、複数のLambda関数で同じ環境変数値を使いたい場合、それぞれの関数ごとに環境変数を指定する必要があります。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

動的に変わる値を複数のLambda関数で共有したい、といった場合であれば、Lambda実行時のパラメータで渡す、DynamoDB等外部ソースに値を格納するといったことも案としてあるのではないかと思います。

Comment: AWSに強いパートナー様にも確認したところ、Ogiwara様と同じ回答をいただきました。それぞれのLambdaに設定するか、別で持っておく必要があるようですね…。